# .pgpass not working as expected - different behaviour on different machines

Tags: postgresql

I know that `.pgpass` file is supposed to handle the logging in process for the users defined in this file. I can't wrap my head around the following that is happening on different machines. I should be clearer when it comes to a "machine". There are three users logging into a server and all of the following commands is run on the server.

User 1: `.pgpass` contains one line: `host:port:db:user:pass`. If I want to execute e.g. `$ psql db -U user` I need to provide the password listed in the file.

User 2: `.pgpass` is empty and there's no need to provide a password (there's no password prompt after the `$ psql db -U user`).

My hypothesis was that as long as the password is defined in the `.pgpass` a password prompt pops up and you must provide a password. But then on the User 3 there's a `.pgpass` file identical to that on the User 1 but no password prompt shows up. How can it be explained?

Comment: Are you running `psql` on the server itself, with no `-h`/`--host` specified? You've probably got [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) configured to use `peer` or `trust` authentication for local connections, both of which bypass password checks.

Comment: Sorry for being too vague at the beginning. I added clarification to the original post. Where is `pg_hba.conf` file located? I couldn't find using `$ find / -name 'pg_hba.conf' 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Connect to the server and run `SHOW hba_file;`. By default, it's in the server's data directory.

Comment: I logged to the database as the `user` from the question (who happens to be a super user for the database we're operating on) by using `$ psql db -U user`. `show hba_file` returns nothing (`show hba_file;` raises syntax error)

Comment: In `psql`, typing `show hba_file <enter> show hba_file; <enter>` will return nothing after the first `<enter>`, and throw a syntax error after the second - until it sees the `;`, it will try to interpret the entire input as a single multi-line command. Make sure you add the `;` after the first command, or just run `psql db -U user -c 'show hba_file'` from the terminal.

Comment: According to `pg_hba.conf`: `# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only \n 
host         all       all   localhost  md5 \n
local        all       all  md5 ` so it seems every user should use the password, but only one of them (me) needs to use a password. Still I can't understand what's happening. `\n` used to indicate the new line

Comment: Hmm, maybe something in [`PGPASSWORD`/`PGPASSFILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)?